# could not be translated. Rewrite the query into a translatable form in Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Currently I want to make a query that obtains information from 3 different tables and between those 3 tables create a relationship so that based on that I can obtain what I require but I also need to group the products for each order that has been made and thus obtain a list of orders and a list of products within each order item.

```
var ordenes = (from ord in myDbContext.orden
                             join prod_ord in myDbContext.prod_orden on ord.idOrden equals prod_ord.idOrden
                             join prod in myDbContext.producto on prod_ord.idProducto equals prod.idProducto
                             where ord.idCliente==clienteIdInt
                           group prod by new { prod,ord,prod_ord } into grp
                           select new 
                             {
                                 IdOrden = grp.Key.ord.idOrden,
                                 Codigo = grp.Key.ord.codigo,
                                 Comentarios = grp.Key.ord.Comentarios,
                                 Fecha = grp.Key.ord.fecha,
                                 Estatus = grp.Key.ord.Estatus,
                                 IdCliente = grp.Key.ord.idCliente,
                                 Prioridad = grp.Key.ord.Prioridad,
                                 Latitud = grp.Key.ord.Latitud,
                                 Longitud = grp.Key.ord.Longitud,
                                 IdDomicilio = grp.Key.ord.IdDomicilio,
                                 idSucursal = grp.Key.ord.IdSucursal,
                                 titulo = "titulo",
                                 producto =(from product in myDbContext.producto where grp.Key.prod_ord.idProducto==product.idProducto select product).ToList()
                             }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Fecha).ToList();
```

But it gives me the following error.

```
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList'
```

I would like to know what part of the query is wrong or why this problem arises.

Comment: Try your last property as this: `producto = grp.ToList()`.

Comment: _"I would like to know what part of the query is wrong or why this problem arises."_ - there's an easy way to find out: start removing parts that it might be. When it works after the part you've removed, you'll know that's the problem.